# OpenSSL retrieving data from a certificate

Tags: php, https, openssl, certificate

I am trying to enable https protocol in my local website. I have implemented uploading mechanism of the certificates and it works like charm. The next thing that I want to implement is to show some key information which are retrieved from the uploaded certificate. By this way the user can see that the certificate is successfully uploaded and working. So for example, I want to show the organization name, expiry date. I tried the following but it returns all the name information. I want to pick the organization name up from this list. Can anyone guide me through?

```
$certInfo  = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($cert_directory . 'ssl.pem'));
echo $certInfo['name'];
```

Another question is, what information would be meaningful for the user to see? I am planning to show organization name and expiry date but perhaps it would be useful to show some other information as well. Can you comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

X.509 can have anywhere from zero to two organization names. Just depends on if the issuer's distinguished name and the subject's distinguished name has them.

Here's what I'd do (using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSL certificate implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/intro.html)):

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...');

echo $x509->getDN(true);
echo '<br />';
echo $x509->getIssuerDN(true);
?>
```

You can get the expiry date by doing this:

```
$expiry = isset($cert['tbsCertificate']['validity']['notAfter']['utcTime']) ?
    $cert['tbsCertificate']['validity']['notAfter']['utcTime'] :
    $cert['tbsCertificate']['validity']['notAfter']['generalTime'];
```